# React - Reset css animation in progress

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

In React, if I have an animation that starts based on a button click, how do I restart that animation?

**jsx**

```
const animationStyle = `countdown ${this.props.duration}s linear infinite forwards`;


<svg id="svg1">
  <circle
    id="c1"
    style={{animation: animationStyle }}
    cx="100"
    cy="100"
    r="80"
  ></circle>
</svg>
```

**.css file**

```
@keyframes countdown {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 500px;
  }
}
```

If I pass down a new duration, it won't immediately start the new animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to remove the svg circle and add it again when you update the duration to be able to reset the animation.

So in react you can do that by keeping a state variable called `resetAnimation` and before updating the duration change the value to `true` this will force component to render then in the callback function of setState revert `resetAnimation` to false again and update duration.

Check code below:

```
export default class Animation extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        duration:5,
        restartAnimation : false 
    }
}


updateDuration() {
    //before updating duration set resetAnimation to true to remove the svg from dom, then in the callback function set it to false and update duration
     this.setState({
         restartAnimation: true
     }, () => {
         requestAnimationFrame(() => {
             this.setState({
                 duration: this.state.duration-1,
                 restartAnimation: false
             })
         })
     })
 }

render() {
    const animationStyle = `countdown ${this.state.duration}s linear infinite forwards`;

    //check if resetAnimation is true don't render the svg ( now we removed the svg from dom)
    if(this.state.restartAnimation)
    {
        return (<div></div>);
    }
    //else if resetAnimation is false render the svg but now the new duration and animation will start from the beginning 
    else
    {
        return (
            <svg id={"svg1"}>
              <circle
                id="c1"
                style={{animation: (this.state.restartAnimation ? "" : animationStyle) }}
                cx="100"
                cy="100"
                r="80"
              >
              </circle>
            </svg>
        );
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks! I did something similar to your suggestion but you're 100% right. Only way to break the animation is to remove the SVG then put it back